# C# Code Switching from Absolute to Relative Paths During Scheduled Task

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, relative-path, absolute-path

I have some C# code that uses Absolute paths to identify file locations. When I debug the code, the paths continue to be absolute (confirmed by using using Console.WriteLine). When the code launches from Windows Task Scheduler (at it's triggered time), the paths display as relative (again, confirmed by Console.WriteLine).  However, if I attempt to run the code directly (using the compiles exe, or launched from Task Scheduler) the paths display as absolute again!

Here's how I call paths:

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string strSCPath = path + @"\Scorecards";
string filePath = strSCPath + @"\" + file + ".txt";
```

And how I verify the relative/absolute condition:

```
Console.WriteLine("Filepath defined as: {0}", filePath");
```

And when I run using Task Scheduler:

```
Filepath defined as .\Scorecards\file.txt
```

But running manually:

```
Filepath defined as D:\Users\Files\Scorecards\file.txt
```

Is there a setting in my code or in Task Scheduler itself I'm failing to set correctly that would cause the above condition?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. Please also see [ask].

Comment: "I have some C# code". You really need to share the code in this question...

Comment: If you're starting from the *current directory*, have you done something to ensure that the *current directory* on startup is set correctly?

Comment: Yes - I ensure that the "Start In" field in the Task Scheduler is D:\Users\Files".  Also - the fact that I can launch from Task Scheduler manually without the paths switching to relative - seems to indicate the code should work as designed....  I'm wondering if this is a Windows issue...

Comment: Is the Task running as the same user that you are testing on?

Comment: Yes - I've ensured that...

Answer (score 0):

What's the output from this? It should tell you where the relative path is resolving to.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(path, "Scorecards"));
Console.WriteLine("Directory defined as: {0}", di.FullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved - it appears another coder modified my code post-display, returning the path call back to relative.  After a thorough thrashing, we've returned to the base code.

Still not sure why the code would act different, but I'm closing this question...

Thanks!